# nmclient object error after running puppet

Tags: centos7

I have puppet installed on my servers. All running CentOS 7.x headless. No GUI installed. However I"m getting the following error:

`Error: Could not create NMClient object: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetManagedObjects" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" doesn't exist`

This might need to go puppet stackexchange. Not sure. I've found stuff about a similar error on kubuntu and something about policy kit causing issues.

---

We are running puppet and its throwing these errors in /var/log/messages.  We think it might be hindering puppet.

Answer (score -1):

NMClient is the freedesktop object for Network Manager, which some ISPs leave on CentOS 7 for some inexplicable reason but in this case it looks like it doesn't exist on your server. I would guess you are pushing network configuration but something isn't set up properly. With CentOS 7 you either have to go with nmclient or remove it so you can use ip and/or ifconfig.